# Web API C# model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, model, asp.net-core-webapi

How do I create a model that will accept this in API POST?

```json
{
    "formId": "ff2f0a7f-aa26-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009",
    "workflowId": "",
    "status": "Draft",
    "formData": {
        "input[f521099a-ae5b-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009]": "0bd946d0-ae5c-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009, b022e9f9-ae78-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009",
        "input[df8dd2e4-ae66-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009][e46ce484-ae66-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009]": "e46ce484-ae66-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009",
        "input[df8dd2e4-ae66-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009][e81189ee-ae66-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009]": "e81189ee-ae66-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009",
        "input[d0cd94fe-ae78-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009]": "asdasd"
    }
}
```

I tried this:

```cs
public record ContentFormAnswerDto(
    [Required, MinLength(36), MaxLength(40)] string FormId,
    [MinLength(36), MaxLength(40)] string? WorkflowId = null,
    string? Status = null,
    string? FormData = null
);

[HttpPost]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(MessageHandlerRm), 201)]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] ContentFormAnswerDto dto)
```

I get:

```json
{
  "errors": {
    "dto": [
      "The dto field is required."
    ],
    "formData": [
      "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'formData', line 5, position 15."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-d80738856fa30bc66e1f7c37838ab707-6e11c03c42b4b6b8-00"
}
```

Comment: and what problem did you face with your code? Did you get any error? Unexpected results?

Comment: I have put more info on what I tried and errors I get - looks like it doesnt like what i pass as formData value

Comment: There are many online JSON-to-C# converters and Visual Studio itself has the option to paste JSON as classes. The only problem is the weird `formData` element that can only be deserialized as `Dictionary<string,string>`. The big problem is that the *keys* contain data, more data than the values themselves

Answer (score 0):

Ok decided on other approach

```json
{
    "formId": "ff2f0a7f-aa26-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009",
    "workflowId": null,
    "status": "Draft",
    "formData": [
        {
            "questionId": "f521099a-ae5b-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009",
            "answer": [
                "0bd946d0-ae5c-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009",
                "b022e9f9-ae78-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009"
            ]
        },
        {
            "questionId": "f521099a-ae5b-11ee-bc5f-0242ac110009",
            "answer": [
                "asdasd"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

#### DTO

```cs
/// <summary>
/// ContentFormAnswer Dto
/// </summary>
/// <param name="FormId"></param>
/// <param name="WorkflowId"></param>
/// <param name="Status"></param>
/// <param name="FormData"></param>
public record ContentFormAnswerDto(
    [Required, MinLength(36), MaxLength(40)] string FormId,
    [MinLength(36), MaxLength(40)] string? WorkflowId = null,
    string? Status = null,
    Input[]? FormData = null
);

/// <summary>
/// Input Dto
/// </summary>
/// <param name="QuestionId"></param>
/// <param name="Answer"></param>
public record Input(
    string QuestionId,
    string[] Answer
);
```